# Buttons also appear in the 2nd view, even though they switch to different ViewController

Tags: ios, swift3

Buttons that appear in the second view are added programmatically. How do I make it not visible in the view?

```
  import UIKit


    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

        var Hotel_Name = [String]()
        var itemView = UIView()

        var identities = [String]()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

//        let buttonAYŞE = Otel_1(text: "AYŞE")
//        let buttonBREZKEMER = Otel_2(text: "BREZ KEMER")
//        
//        buttonAYŞE.alpha = 0
//        buttonBREZKEMER.alpha = 0


            identities = ["listTable", "scrollview"]


//****** Aşağıdaki kapalı olan JSONSerialization yapısı açıldığında web servisten çektiği verileri tableview'e aktarmaktadır. Üstteki HotelModel fonksiyonu kapatldığı taktirde.
            let urlString = "http://service.ceylaner.com.tr/hotelapi/api/hotel/GetHotels?Company_id=1&Language_id=1"
            let url = URL(string: urlString)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                }
                else
                {
                    do
                    {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray

                        if let jsonDic = json
                        {
                            for i in 0..<jsonDic.count
                            {
                                if let basliklar = jsonDic[i] as? NSDictionary
                                {
                                    if let Hotel_NameArray = basliklar["Hotel_Name"] as? NSString
                                    {
                                        self.Hotel_Name.append(Hotel_NameArray as String)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                            self.tableview?.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()

            view.addSubview(Otel_1(text: "AYŞE DFDFDNKFDFMKVFKVKNFVND"))
            view.addSubview(Otel_2(text: "BREZ KEMER"))

        }
        //buttons
       public func Otel_1(text:String) -> UIButton {
            let btn_1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
            //Set a frame for the button. Ignored in AutoLayout/ Stack Views
            btn_1.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 555, width: 170, height: 100)
            //Set background color
            btn_1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightText
            //State dependent properties title and title color
            btn_1.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
            btn_1.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            btn_1.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
            btn_1.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            btn_1.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            btn_1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            return btn_1
        }
        func Otel_2(text:String) -> UIButton {
            let btn_2 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
            //Set a frame for the button. Ignored in AutoLayout/ Stack Views
            btn_2.frame = CGRect(x: 195, y: 555, width: 170, height: 100)
            //Set background color
            btn_2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightText
            //btn_1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            //State dependent properties title and title color
            btn_2.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
            btn_2.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            btn_2.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
            btn_2.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            btn_2.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            btn_2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            return btn_2
        }

        func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
//            Button action'ı ile diğer Main viewcontroller'ından setting viewcontroller'ına geçer.
//            let goBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoView")
            var InfoView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoView") as! UIViewController
            self.present(InfoView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            InfoView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical // animasyon ekleme

        }


        // tableView Methodları
        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return Hotel_Name.count
        }
        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
            cell.InfoLabel.text = Hotel_Name[indexPath.row]
            cell.InfoLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            cell.InfoImage.image = UIImage(named:"logo")
            return cell
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 150
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
            let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

    }
```

The button on the screen is clicked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhEdM.jpg)

The 2nd screen showing the buttons on the 1st screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waObp.jpg)

I created the UIButton programmatically. Buttonaction is being done. The buttons 1 on the screen are being transferred to the 2nd screen. Do I have to split the views, I'm showing the wrong view. Or is the action adding something extra?

I've added all of the code that I wrote in the ViewController.

Comment: Show the implementation of `buttonAction` please

Comment: How are you navigating to the next screen?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong writing style that I have done, yet I am new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write it like

```
Otel_1(text: "AYŞE").alpha = 0
```

you're actually creating a new button and at the end, you're hiding it.

Each call for `Otel_1` function is returning an instance of a new button,
so as a solution for this you can declare the buttons outside of the function to expand its scope and lifetime 
like:

```
let btn_2 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
```

and then use it inside the function

```
func Otel_2(text:String) -> UIButton {
    btn_2.frame = CGRect(x: 195, y: 555, width: 170, height: 100)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manar, for all your help, the problem was solved.